# Use form to interact with database

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm trying to make a application with Silex and I want to create a form which will allow to add things in my database.

I added Symfony's components but I don't find documentation to create this kind of form, only connect forms.
How do I use Symfony's components like:

```
$data = $form->getData();
$app['form']->persist($data);
$app['form']->flush();
return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('homepage'));
```

Or should I do something like that?

```
$data = $form->getData();
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `testdb`.`video` (`id` ,`titre`)
VALUES (NULL ,  $data['name']";
$app['dbs']['mysql_write']->execute($sql);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go for either:

- [plain PDO](http://php.net/pdo)
- [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal) ([DoctrineServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html) ships with silex)
- [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm) ([a few](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/wiki/Third-Party-ServiceProviders) providers available)

Whatever you do, for the love of god, [use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thanx for your help. I finally chose Doctrine DBAL